# nil dereference may occur on Time.new.to_date.to_time

Tags: ruby

Why RubyMine gives a warning `nil dereference may occur` on `Time.new.to_date.to_time`?

```rb
def main(from_date = nil)
  from_date ||= Time.new.to_date.to_time
end
```

I want to fill variable `from_date` in method with either an argument passed to the method or the current date (Time.new.to_date.to_time).

In what case can happen `dereference may occur`?

Comment: Regardless of the error, this is a somewhat convoluted bit of code. If you want `from_date` to be a **date**, which defaults to **today**, then you can probably just do: `def main(from_date = Date.today)`. And if you *really* need it it to actually be `Time` instance (??!!!), then: `def main(from_date = Date.today.to_time)`.

Comment: @TomLord, I do not need current *date*, I need current date *with* zero hours/minutes/seconds. 2019-06-25 00:00:00 (begin of current day).

Comment: That's exactly what `Date.today` is. A `Date` object has no notion of hours, minutes, seconds, etc. And it would be a rather odd requirement that a variable named `from_date` must be a `Time`, not a `Date`. Regardless, as I said, `Date.today.to_time` returns an identical value to your approach.

Comment: For what it's worth though, I have no idea why RubyMine reports `dereference may occur`. All I can say is that the code can be better written; and doing so would likely make the warning go away.

Comment: @TomLord if `nil` is explicitly passed, then `def main(from_date = Date.today.to_time)` does not work as `nil` is still a valid argument thus replacing the default value for `from_date` (this may be what RubyMine is actually warning about). That being said I agree with `Date.today.to_time`